# Implementing "copy constructor" vs. using copy()

Tags: python

What is generally preferred, in terms of python conventions + speed? something like:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, other_object=None):
        if other_object:
            self.value = other_object.value
        else:
            self.value = something
```

and then

```
obj = Object(other_object)
```

or, using copy():

```
from copy import copy
obj = copy(other_object)
```

Comment: Why the hell do you want to provide your own copy implementation? Consider a deeply nested object with an arbitrary structure: your copy implementation is subject to be error-prone...so why?

Comment: I'm just asking. and let's assume my object is very simple, like in the example. timeit showed very poor results for copy() vs. my implementation.

Comment: The semantics of copying and a new instance are different; don't use an instance factory when you want a copy of an existing instance. It's a question of separation of responsibilities; it could be that you implement `__copy__` in terms of calling the constructor, but keep them separate methods.

Comment: It's actually hard *not* to be faster than `copy`, and `deepcopy` is absurdly slow.  I've seen them be ~10-80 times slower than being explicit (on a quick test for the OP's case, I get 15x and 40x.)  Separating the concerns like MP suggests is a good idea, and avoiding `(deep)copy` can be necessary to prevent it becoming an unexpected bottleneck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The things are very simple, considering the documentation of the `copy` module:

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can
>   define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is
>   called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional
>   arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy
>   operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. If the
>   `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the `deepcopy()` function with the component
>   as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

So, if you feel that the standard `copy()` or `deepcopy()` works slow or has some other issues, just implement one of the methods mentioned above. That way you are sticking to the well-known Python objects copying mechanism, still copying the object the way you want it to be copied.